# PhoneGap webview function calls from native code not executing after font change

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordovawebview

I'm developing an app which has partial functionality implemented in PhoneGap and partial in native Android. It's works great mostly. I don't save the state when my app is killed by OS on configuration change, memory recovering etc. Now when came back to app after font change, the PhoneGap function calls from native code don't execute, rather these calls are being queued at PhoneGap side. When an action is performed on PhoneGap `WebView`, all those queued calls are executed. Does anybody have any idea about this strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed after debugging in Cordova. I was having a few plugin calls in `onResume()` on main activity. When the app resumed after `onCreate()` is called followed by `onResume()` and this process is faster than normal launch. Cordava is not fully loaded in this time so plugin calls, which are in `onResume()` followed by all after coming plugin calls, are stucked in Cordova queue and never executed again. For fix, skipped the plugin calls in `onResume()` when `savedInstanceState != null`.